# How to restart naudio after "Buffer Full" error and PlayBackStopped set on Play

Tags: naudio

Does anyone know how to `Restart` naudio playback after it produces a "Buffer Full" error and the player status is PlayBackStopped?

I am streaming audio to naudio using a `BufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples` when the error occurs.

I have tried to clear the buffer and restart the player using the following which doesn't solve the problem. Audio does not continue.

```
 try
        {
            if (player.PlaybackState == NAudio.Wave.PlaybackState.Stopped)
            {
                bufferedWaveProvider.ClearBuffer();
                player.Play();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogMessage($"Error: Restart of Player failed.  {ex.ToString()}");
        }
```

I have also tried disposing of the player and `BufferedWaveProvider`, reinstantiating them and starting the player and that also doesn't work.

It would appear that some condition occurs within the naudio library itself and that it cannot be cleared.

The only way I can get the audio playing again is to end and restart the application.

Any guidance or suggestions would be much appreciated.